# FBSDK findByGraphPath (me) doesn't return an email, even with permissions and explicit fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, fbsdk

I try to fetch at least id, username and email from a logged in Facebook user. I first login using the permission type: Email. And if succeeded try to fetch an FBSDKGraphRequest, which returns every possible value but email.

I tried adding permissions like public_profile as well, but in any case I try, I do not get email. I looked in the developers dashboard, and email seems to be approved by default.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        return;
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
        return;
    }

    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, gender, first_name, last_name, locale, email"}];

    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            return;
        }

        NSLog(@"Fetched user: %@", result);
    }];
}];
```

Comment: Keep in mind that a) not every user _has_ and email address on file with Facebook (f.e. when they registered using their mobile), and b) the email address will only be returned if the user has verified it.

Comment: Ouch, found out that was the case ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the same problem and I was lucky enough to find the solution in the comment. It is given by CBroe. I think that this should be posted as an answer.

So... in my case the problem was that the user had not confirmed his email. Once I've confirmed it I received the email from Facebook. All the acknowledgemnts are to CBroe

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be like this

```
-(void)loginWithFacebookButtonTouchUpInside
{
    if(![FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"public_profile"] fromViewController:nil handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                // Process error
            }
            else if (result.isCancelled)
            {
                // Handle cancellations
            }
            else
            {
                // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
                // should check if specific permissions missing
                [self userLoggedIn];
            }

        }];
    }else{
       //error "Authentication is not done"
    }
}

- (void)userLoggedIn
{
    [FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:NO];
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"name, email,first_name,last_name"}]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id userInfo, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             {

             }
         }
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code on Login Button click.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[loginManager setLoginBehavior:FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount];
[loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
{
    if (error)
    {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        [loginManager logOut];
    }
    else if (result.isCancelled)
    {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        [loginManager logOut];
    }
    else
    {
        if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"publish_actions"])
        {
            NSTimeInterval addTimeInterval = 60*60*24*365*50;
            NSDate *expireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:addTimeInterval];
            NSDate *refreshDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:addTimeInterval];

            FBSDKAccessToken *newAccessToken = [[FBSDKAccessToken alloc] initWithTokenString:[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] tokenString] permissions:nil declinedPermissions:nil appID:FACEBOOK_ID userID:[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] userID] expirationDate:expireDate refreshDate:refreshDate];
            [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:newAccessToken];
            [self FacebookUserInfo];
        }
        else
        {
            [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
            {
                if (error)
                {
                    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                    [loginManager logOut];
                }
                else if (result.isCancelled)
                {
                    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                    [loginManager logOut];
                }
                else
                {
                    NSTimeInterval addTimeInterval = 60*60*24*365*50;
                    NSDate *expireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:addTimeInterval];
                    NSDate *refreshDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:addTimeInterval];

                    FBSDKAccessToken *newAccessToken = [[FBSDKAccessToken alloc] initWithTokenString:[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] tokenString] permissions:nil declinedPermissions:nil appID:FACEBOOK_ID userID:[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] userID] expirationDate:expireDate refreshDate:refreshDate];
                    [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:newAccessToken];
                    [self FacebookUserInfo];
                }
            }];
        }
    }
}];
```

Once you get Access Token call following method.

```
- (void)FacebookUserInfo
{
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields":@"name,email,first_name,last_name"}]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error)
         {
             NSDictionary *dict = @{@"id":result[@"id"],
                                          @"name":result[@"first_name"],
                                          @"email":result[@"email"]
                                          };
             [self saveData:dict];
         }
         else
         {

         }
     }];
}
```

May be this is helpful for you.

Comment: The FBSDKAccessToken exchange works, but I think the SDK does this implicitly by default. Also, the strategy still doen't give me access to the user's email.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm your email on Facebook. The problem will be resolved.